# Programmatically change IE registry without restarting it

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-7, registry, webbrowser-control, internet-explorer-9

I have a Web Browser Controller embedded in an MFC application (using IE9 underneath).
I want to change some IE9 registry keys programmatically within the application (e.g., the FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION key that enforce IE9 standard mode). I want to do so without restarting my MFC application. Is it possible by any means?

I guess that when IE9 itself let the user change it's settings, and the new settings are valid without restarting IE - this is probably done by Registry callback function that monitor some registry keys and when it being called IE re-read those keys.

10x,

Guy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many settings will only become active after restarting the browser. Other settings will work immediately, but not because IE9 monitors the registry. You just do the setting in the browser, so the browser can take the setting and apply it, just as it writes it to the registry. It doesn't actively monitor register changes.

In your application, you can destroy and recreate the WebBrowser control after you've done the registry changes. That way you don't have to restart the application, but only 'restart' the browser inside the application. :)